# Time range slider for Bokeh

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

Does Bokeh has time range slider functionality like `daterangeslider()`?, I want a time range slider of 24 hours with start time as 00:00:00 and end time time as 00:00:00 for next day, tried to use `daterangeslider()` but got the error: `function takes at most 3 arguments (6 given)`, looks like `daterangeslider()` does not support time range. Any way to achieve this in Bokeh?

```
DateRangeSlider(title='Time Range: ', start=date(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
end=date(2020, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0), value=(date(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), date(2020, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0)), step=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you're seeing is due to the `date` constructor accepting only 3 arguments. You probably wanted to use `datetime`.

As of Bokeh 0.14, `Date` instances also accept `datetime` so something like this works. Note that I also had to change the `format` because by default the slider shows only the date.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from bokeh.models import DateRangeSlider

start = datetime.now()
end = start + timedelta(days=1)
slider = DateRangeSlider(value=(start, end), start=start, end=end, format="%x, %X")
```

Comment: But this won't allow me choose a specific time during the day, I can't see time change when dragging the slider.

Comment: @efsee Sorry, I focused too much on the error and completely misinterpreted the question. I've updated the answer. If you really need a proper implementation of `DateTimeRangeSlider` and can't figure it out yourself, I can probably come up with something. Not sure how soon though.

Comment: Well, just edited the answer again. TIL that `Date` in Bokeh is really a `datetime`, and all you had to do is change the `format`.